# modify object property and add it to object as nested properties

Tags: javascript, html, object, nested

I'm creating and populating an object with user input from x `<input>` fields.
So far I've managed to create the object and populate it with the user input.
However I'm stuck on my next step.

I want to grab and modify the user input and separate it into nested properties using comma to split.

This might be an easy task, but I can't come up with a working solution.
How can I achieve this?
(not sure how well I explained myself, so I posted an example for the desired output)

The html: (potentially more input fields than those 2x2)

```
<input type="text" name="test_1.Title" class="tests">
<input type="text" name="test_1.String" class="tests">
<input type="text" name="test_2.Title" class="tests">
<input type="text" name="test_2.String" class="tests">
```

```
function objectMaker() {

  function objectSubs(obj, keys, value) {
    let key = keys.shift()
    if (keys.length) {
      obj[key] = obj[key] || {}
      objectSubs(obj[key], keys,  value)
      return
    }
    obj[key] = value
  }

  function grabTestData(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('tests');
    var testObject = {}
    Object.keys(inputs).forEach(i => {
      let inputName = inputs[i].getAttribute('name');
      objectSubs(testObject, inputName.split('.'), inputs[i].value)
    })
  }
  grabTestData()

}
```

current object:

```
var testObject = {
  tests1: {
    title: "random title",
    string: "somestring, other string, and anotherString",
  },
  tests2: {
    title: "other random title",
    string: "thisString, thatString, a String there",
  },
}
```

desired object:

```
var testObject = {
  tests1: {
    title: "random title",
    string: {
      substring1: "somestring",
      substring2: "other string",
      substring3: "and anotherString",
    },
  },
  tests2: {
    title: "other random title",
    string: {
      substring1: "thisString",
      substring2: "thatString",
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to use the same general function for the Title and String inputs, because Title doesn't get split up.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want a nested object instead of an array for the substrings?

Comment: actually no, there is no real reason. An array for the substrings works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a function to convert the object over to your desired format:

```js
function splitStrings(obj) {
  Object.values(obj).forEach(val => val.string = Object.fromEntries(val.string.split(',').map((e, i) => ["substring"+(i+1), e.trim()])));
  return obj;
}
```

- takes the values of the object with `Object.values` to get an array of your `{ title, string }` objects
- `forEach` object, sets `.string` to an object created from converting each comma separated value in the string to an entry of format `[substringN, value]`

---

Demo:

```js
var testObject = {
  tests1: {
    title: "random title",
    string: "somestring, other string, and anotherString",
  },
  tests2: {
    title: "other random title",
    string: "thisString, thatString, a String there",
  },
}

function splitStrings(obj) {
  Object.values(obj).forEach(val => val.string = Object.fromEntries(val.string.split(',').map((e, i) => ["substring"+(i+1), e.trim()])));
  return obj;
}

splitStrings(testObject);
console.log(testObject);
```

---

If you want an array of substrings instead, you can do:

```js
function splitStrings(obj) {
  Object.values(obj).forEach(val => val.string = val.string.split(',').map(e=>e.trim());
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Now looking at your answer, I believe I was thinking to complicated yesterday.
Thank you so much for this!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var testObject = {
  tests1: {
    title: "random title",
    string: "somestring, other string, and anotherString"
  },
  tests2: {
    title: "other random title",
    string: "thisString, thatString, a String there"
  }
};
testObject.tests1.string = testObject.tests1.string.split(",");
testObject.tests2.string = testObject.tests2.string.split(",");
console.log(testObject);
```

**The output for this code is:**

```
{
  tests1: {
    title: 'random title',
    string: [ 'somestring', ' other string', ' and anotherString' ]
  },
  tests2: {
    title: 'other random title',
    string: [ 'thisString', ' thatString', ' a String there' ]     
  }
}
```